# SQL query to run data from two connection - Oracle and SQLServer connection

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL developer. I need to create query to get data from two different connection, Oracle connection and SQLServer connection. How can I create link between the connections or how should I proceed?

I have tried to create database link but didn't succeed and received below error.

```
Create database link XXXX
connect to XXXX
identified by "XXXX"
using 'XXXX\XXXX';
```

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
Create database link xxxx
connect to xxxx
IDENTIFIED BY "xxxx"
using 'xxxx\xxxx'
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

I get the same error message at any values so can the reason really be insufficient privileges? Is this even the correct way or is it even possible to use one query to get data from these two connections?

Comment: [See this question and its answer on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111985/step-by-step-establish-a-connection-between-sql-server-2014-and-oracle-12c)

Comment: Define "didn't succeed".   What was the error message?

Comment: Error message added

Comment: You know whats the funny part is - it actually tells you what to do - *"Ask your database administrator...."* Do you think, someone here can solve this? We don't have access to your system - your admin has. And then, even if we give you a command to grant privilege, you couldn't execute it, because you don't have such privilege.